# Python sorting array according to date

Tags: python, sorting

How can i sort python list according to maximum date which is combined with string

```
['', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc', 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc']
```

above is the list and expected result is this

```
['q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc','']
```

I wrote a script which is not sorting but priniting only one value at end

```
a = ['q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc','']
print max(a)
```

Result:

```
q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc
```

How can i get expected output like this

Expected output:

```
['q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc','q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc','']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function to extract the date from your string with a regular expression, and use that as key to `sorted`:

```
import re

l = ['',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc',
     'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc']

def get_date(line):
    pattern = '.*_(\d{8}).doc'
    m = re.match(pattern, line)
    if m:
        return int(m.group(1))
    else:
        return -1 # or do something else with lines that contain no date


print sorted(l, key=get_date, reverse=True)
```

prints:

```
['q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc', 
 '']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be easier solvable by using the built-in function `str.rpartition('_')` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition).

I'm assuming all your files have the same format of course, in that case the above function would always return `<date>.doc`. Then you just have to remove the `.doc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an alternate one line solution *(kind of)*. You have to first clean the list by removing empty elements.

```
given_list = filter(None, given_list)
sorted(given_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split(".")[0][-8:], "%Y%m%d"), reverse=True)
```

Or to simplify it like in [BioGeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35890966/2932244), instead of using `datetime` simply convert into `int` and sort on it.

```
given_list = filter(None, given_list)
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0][-8:]), reverse=True)
```

*Output:*

```
['q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20120103.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_reSume_311386_20120103.doc',
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_Resume_311386_20100901.doc',
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20100901.doc', 
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_RESUME_311386_20091012.doc',
 'q//Attachments/Swoop_coverletter_311386_20091012.doc']
```